# How to get notified when "Add account " Activity has finished

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that uses google push c2dm.
When I start my application I check to see whatever the phone has a Google account registered or not. 
If there is no account I use startActivity to start the "Add account" activity

```
Intent addAccountIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(addAccountIntent);
```

Is there a way to get notified when this activity has finished, so that I can confirm that there is a Google account active on the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your activity using [startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). You will get notified later in [onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29).

See example [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20131013014106/http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/calendar/LaunchActivity.java.html) (archive.org).